# C# why does assigning an event handler use a += operator and not =

Tags: c#, events, delegates, compound-assignment

Maybe I'm not googling hard enough, but I'd like to understand the syntax '+=' when assigning an event. For example we use:

```
myButton.Click += MyClickEvent;
```

rather than:

```
myButton.Click = MyClickEvent;
```

Why is this the case? Is there some maths going on here? Why would you add addresses?

Comment: If an event is invoked, several methods can be executed. Hence you add these methods to the event, using the `+=` operator. If one method should not be executed any longer, you can remove it again, using the `-=` operator

Comment: @SomeBody - Ah, so myButton.Click effectively maintains a list of methods to call. I did not know that. Thank you. Now it all makes sense.

Comment: Because you *attach* a delegate to the event and this means adding something to existing something, this is best represented as += in C#

Comment: the term here is "multicast" - all delegates created in C# are multicast; at some point way back in the origins of .NET unicast delegates were a thing, but in reality: they're not (it *may* still be possible to create a try unicast delegate via IL, but I'd need to check)

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't believe it's possible in *MSIL* although other implementations may allow it. [**ECMA-335](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/3/733AD403-90B2-4064-A81E-01035A7FE13C/MS%20Partition%20II.pdf) Section 14.6 Implementation-Specific (Microsoft)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An event can have more than one handler, so it is not a assignment but a subscription.
You could do the following and all handlers would be called.

```
myButton.Click += MyClickEvent;
myButton.Click += MyClickEvent1;
myButton.Click += MyClickEvent2;
```

To unsubscribe from the event use

```
myButton.Click -= MyClickEvent2;
```